# No Longer Receiving Message Notifications on Lock Screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, notifications, lock-screens, 4.3-jelly-bean

I have a SG3 recently updated to Jelly Bean 4.3. When the update ran, I received message previews on the lock screen, accessed them without trouble, and enjoyed the feature. In the last 24-36 hours, these previews have ceased, and I can no longer swipe to the lock screen where the message previews used to appear.

The preview setting is still checked, and I continue to receive notifications and previews in my status bar.

Comment: Is the widget still on the lock screen? It may just be that you need to add that back in.

Comment: @RossC I don't think this can be a duplicate because the answers on that question don't make any sense as answers to this question.

Comment: @DanHulme Yeah I made a mistake, sorry. I coudn't undo it so I gave an answer to make up for it.

Answer (score 1):

Android 4.3 has protection by default to disallow Lock Screen Widgets:

[image]

Firstly you need to go to `Settings > My Device > Lock Screen` as above and enable "Multiple Widgets"

You can change the SMS notifications in the SMS app > Settings > Notifications

As an alternative for anyone interested I would recommend [Dash Clock lock screen Widget](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.nurik.roman.dashclock&hl=en_GB)

This is a HIGHLY customisable Lock Screen Widget. You can have SMS/Missed Calls/Stardate (seriously)/Hangouts/Battery and lots more via extensions. You can customise the look and feel of the clock to be JellyBean, KitKat etc too!

[image]